# Disable all expandable usercards when offline

Tags: feature-request, user-card

When I’m offline, hovering over an expandable usercard has no effect — the data can’t be loaded. I am suggesting that the shadow of the usercard disappear on an `offline` event, and appear on the `online` event:

JS:

```
$(window).on('online', function() {
  $('body').removeClass('offline');
}).on('offline', function() {
  $('body').addClass('offline');
});
```

CSS:

```
body:not(.offline) .user-info.user-hover .user-gravatar32,
body:not(.offline) .user-info.user-hover .user-gravatar48 {
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=135,strength=3, color=#808080);
}
.user-info.user-hover .user-gravatar32,
.user-info.user-hover .user-gravatar48
  border-collapse:separate;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 1s;
          transition: box-shadow 1s;
 }
```

Comment: Any particular reason why? If you're in offline mode then you know you're in offline mode and that it won't work. What benefit comes from explicitly removing the shadow? There's not exactly any harm in leaving it there even if it won't do anything.

Comment: Nothing will work when offline. Voting, commenting, posting. Why of all things you want to remove this minor thing? If anything, have it disable everything so that you won't click for nothing.

Comment: @animuson All the other actions show an error. This one doesn’t.